# Python: Joining adjacent members of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that will always be of even length.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What's the best way I can turn it into this:

```
mylist = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

I have this, and it works, but it seems hugely verbose:

```
myotherlist = []
for x in xrange(0, len(mylist), 2):
    myotherlist.append(mylist[x] + mylist[x + 1])
```

Which returns this:

```
>>> myotherlist
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a pretty nifty comprehension with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> mylist[::2]
['a', 'c', 'e']
>>> mylist[1::2]
['b', 'd', 'f']
>>>
>>> myotherlist = [a+b for a, b in zip(mylist[::2],mylist[1::2])] #This line does the work
>>> myotherlist
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

I've included multiple lines to make it clear, but its really only one line doing the operation

Comment: This is basically a manual version of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711993/100297) on the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
>>> [''.join([x, y]) for x, y in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])]
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 1):

I live for helper generators. The only thing is that the obvious one yields tuples, and they need to be added together to form strings again. Still I prefer this over making a string specific generator...

```
def pairs(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        yield i.next(), i.next()

myList = [a + b for a, b in pairs(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])]

myList2 = [a + b for a, b in pairs("abcdef")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to get it on one line

```
myotherlist = [mylist[x] + mylist[x+1] for x in xrange(0, len(mylist), 2)]
```

but it doesn't save you much.